# UIActionSheet can't show as expected in iOS9

Tags: uialertview, ios9, uiactionsheet

I found my app can't show UIActionSheet as expected in iOS9。
when I show action sheet, the cornerRadius is big than normal cornerRadius at first, and it will recover to the normal cornerRadius in a very short time。[link of images](http://triplecc.github.io/blog/2015-10-01-uiactionsheetbug/)

Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Renders with edge antialiasing(UIViewEdgeAntialiasing) in your Info.plist