# iOS 9 - Action Controller Bug

Tags: objective-c, ios9, uialertcontroller

I have a problem which I really can't find a solution. 
I use the UIActionController to display an action sheet and it looks very weird. If you look very closely to the 2 images you can notice that the corner radius is higher when presenting than when is fully presented and the lines are bigger and darker. And it makes a weird blink to normal when it's fully presented.

The code for this one is irrelevant, it's a basic Alert Controller with 3 actions.

Notice: It happens in the whole app. Not only in one place.

[image]

[EDIT] Code:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [[UIAlertController alloc] init];

UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LOCLZ(@"See Profile") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [self seeProfile];
}];

UIAlertAction *secondAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LOCLZ(@"Unmatch") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [self unmatchUser];
}];

UIAlertAction *thirdAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LOCLZ(@"Report") style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [AlertView alertWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Error"]
                       title:LOCLZ(@"Alert")
                 description:LOCLZ(@"You're about to report this user as abusive or fake. Do you want to continue ?")
           cancelButtonTitle:LOCLZ(@"NO")
          confirmButtonTitle:LOCLZ(@"YES")
                confirmBlock:^{
                    [self unmatchUser];
                    [self reportUser];
                }];
}];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LOCLZ(@"Cancel") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];

[alertController addAction:firstAction];
[alertController addAction:secondAction];
[alertController addAction:thirdAction];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for creating your UIAlertController? I think you might be adding it to the wrong viewcontroller. Like a parent or something

Comment: Just edited with code

Comment: I don't see what you'd like to resolve actually; and _why_...

Comment: I've uploaded a gif.. Maybe the problem will be noticed better

Comment: I believe this is normal behaviour for the animation. Can you show us an example of how you would want it to look like?

Comment: I've checked other apps like Whatsapp and there it's smooth.. no weird changes after presented

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889588/uiactionsheet-cant-show-as-expected-in-ios9/33774092#33774092

Comment: Yes. The antialiasing was causing this problem. But I need antialiasing for other animations.